# Ways to Overcome Damage Reduction in E6

Tags: dnd-3.5e, e6

Aside from using the requisite materials (Such as silver or adamantine) or fulfilling the right conditions (such as using a piercing weapon or a good aligned weapon) are there any ways other than the ones I'm listing below to bypass damage reduction in [E6](http://www.myth-weavers.com/wiki/index.php/Epic_6).

**Already Know About**

- Sense Weakness
- Deteriorating Blast

**Relevant House Rules**

- Items cannot have a Caster Level higher than 8
- No Spells higher than 4th level
- Polymorph and Lesser Planar Ally are banned

Comment: Power Attack can _theoretically_ penetrate any kind of damage reduction no more than 6, but given how high would their AC be, you aren't considering that as a solution, right?

Comment: No, I'm not. Yes you can totally just out-damage the DR but a lot of our party don't do chunk damage. What I meant with my question was an actual way of avoiding DR altogether.

Comment: An indirect method - but if the enemies can suffocate, consider drowning or similar methods for eliminating them as an option.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**Mountain Hammer**

*Mountain Hammer* is a nifty little maneuver out of *Tome of Battle* that adds 2d6 damage to a melee attack and ignores both hardness and damage reduction for the attack. It's part of the Stone Dragon discipline (note: it's got a less-powerful cousin in the Devoted Spirit discipline). You can pick it up with three levels in any of the initiating classes (Warblade, Swordsage, or Crusader) or via the Martial Study feat as a sixth level anything else (note: to meet prerequisites you may have to take Martial Study more than once).

**Shards of Granite**

Also from *Tome of Battle*, Shards of Granite is a tactical feat that lets you ignore damage reduction and hardness while fighting if you meet certain conditions. You'll need the Stone Power feat to qualify for it.

**Energy Damage**

Energy damage (fire, cold, electricity, acid, sonic, negative energy, etc) is not subject to damage reduction, and is instead subject to energy resistance.